# ajax GET request does not show params in the URL

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

I'm trying to do GET request on a form using jQuery AJAX function, but the problem is that I dont see the parameters in the URL:

Here is the code:

```
<form id="search_form" method="GET" action="">
    <input id="seach_input" type="text" name="q">
    <button id="search_btn" class="btn btn-warning" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Here the Javascript code:

```
$("#search_form").on('submit', function(e) {

    $.ajax({
        url: "index.html",
        type: "GET",
        data: {name: "hello"},
        success: function() {
            console.log("success);
        }
    });

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

After I do submit, I want the URL to look like this:

```
http://localhost/search.html?q=value
```

I know e.preventDefault(); is the reason why the parameters does not appear in the URL, but I need to do it this was without refreshing the page, and at the same time, I want to see the params when I do GET request.

Please help!

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `return false` instead preventDefault?;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want can be done in modern browsers like Chrome, Safari, FF4+, and IE10 using window.history.pushState.

A good article is here http://spoiledmilk.com/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page/

You would need to add something like this into your code.

```
window.history.pushState(“object or string”, “Title”, “/new-url”);
```

Also if you dont want the user to be able to navigate back then use replaceState instead

```
window.history.replaceState(“object or string”, “Title”, “/another-new-url”);
```

Comment: Thanks, I will do it that way